# Python type hinted Dict syntax error mutable default is not allowed. Use 'default factory'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure why the interpreter is complaining about this typed Dict. For both instantiations, I get a "**Mutable default is not allowed. Used default factory**" syntax error. I'm using python 3.7.3

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict

@dataclass
class Test:
    foo: Dict[str, int] = {}
    bar: Dict[str, float] = {'blah': 2.0}
```

Figured it out. It's the @dataclass annotation that's causing the issue. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Probably to save you from the mutable default argument issues. All instances would have the same exact dictionaries if this was allowed, which is almost certainly not what you want. I believe the doc pages for data classes go over the factory alternative.

Comment: Will check it out. Thanks @Carcigenicate

Comment: I can't stop surprising at how Python is incredibly messy. The runtime error itself is baffling: I am using a dataclass decorator, and I am literally _forced_ to see a **runtime** reminder that attributes are static! Why isn't the dataclass decorator providing a default factory by default then? What if this was intentional? Good grief.

Comment: @alelom what baffles you is that there is no "static" in python. It is sorta simulated (usually by treating stuff that is executed when a module is loaded as the "static part of runtime"), but in the end python does everything in runtime

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yup, it's `dataclass` raising to avoid your accidentally giving the same dict to every Test object instantiated with the default.

You could tweak the above to provide a default factory (a function which creates a *new* dict each time the default is needed) with the following:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict

@dataclass
class Test:
    foo: Dict[str, int] = field(default_factory=dict)
    bar: Dict[str, float] = field(default_factory=lambda: {'blah': 2.0})
```

Comment: any other simpler ways to work around this? I'm trying to use dataclasses to make some editable config files and this approach makes everything unusable - so much line noise.

Comment: I have the same or similar question (and intent) as @dcsan (above). Any thoughts for a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I can't stop surprising at how Python is incredibly messy. The runtime error itself is baffling: I am using a dataclass decorator, and I am literally _forced_ to see a **runtime** reminder that attributes are static! Why isn't the dataclass decorator providing a default factory by default then? What if this was intentional? Good grief.

Comment: Why is it bad to “give the same dict to every Test object instantiated with the default"?

Comment: because when you modify it in an instance, it will be modified in all other instances as well.

Comment: `"any other simpler ways to work around this?"` You might find pydantic models to be a little less verbose: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/fields/#default-values (they also give you validation)