# Correct way to initialize an Optional Dict with type hint in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-dataclasses

I want to initialize a dataclass dictionary with **type hint**(key should be string, the value should be another dataclass's instances) called `usr_orders` that does NOT require user init upon initializing instances. Based on my understanding `Optional` is the `union(.., None)`, so I went with:

```py
@dataclass
class User:
    usr_orders: Optional[Dict[str, BookOrder]] = Dict
```

But when I try to modify it using key-value I got the following error: `TypeError: '_GenericAlias' object does not support item assignment`

```py
def update_usr_orders(self, book_order:BookOrder):
    self.usr_orders[book_order.order_id] = book_order # book_order: BookOrder is a dataclass instance
```

This error seems to be caused by the optional Dict definition. But I don't know how to solve this. Does anyone know why I cannot update the `usr_orders`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to import a field and use a `default_factory`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional, Dict

@dataclass
class BookOrder():
    id: str

@dataclass
class User:
    usr_orders: Optional[Dict[str, BookOrder]] = field(default_factory=dict)

    def update_usr_orders(self, book_order:BookOrder):
        self.usr_orders[book_order.id] = book_order

a = BookOrder('1')
u = User()
u.update_usr_orders(a)
print(u.usr_orders)
```

Part of the issue is that you were using `Dict` as a default field for the data class. `Dict` is a type hint; I think you were meaning to use `dict()` or `{}` - however, this would not work. Try it and see for yourself! You'll end up with this error: `ValueError: mutable default <class 'dict'> for field usr_orders is not allowed: use default_factory`. This is a dataclass thing where it prevents you from using 1 dictionary for multiple instances.

[Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222110/python-type-hinted-dict-syntax-error-mutable-default-is-not-allowed-use-defaul)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I tried to use `dict()` for initialization but got the error you mentioned. This answer is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add on to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792009/10237506), a note that in Python 3.7+, you can also declare the dataclass using new-style annotations available via a `__future__` import. This should allow you to do away with `typing` imports in this case.

```py
from __future__ import annotations  # This can be removed in Python 3.10+

from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class BookOrder:
    id: str


@dataclass
class User:
    usr_orders: dict[str, BookOrder] | None = field(default_factory=dict)

    def update_usr_orders(self, book_order: BookOrder):
        self.usr_orders[book_order.id] = book_order


a = BookOrder('1')
u = User()
u.update_usr_orders(a)
print(u.usr_orders)
```

Answer (score 0):

Youre using:

```py
usr_orders = Optional[Dict[str, BookOrder]] = Dict
```

instead of:

```py
usr_orders: Optional[Dict[str, BookOrder]] = Dict
```

replace `=` by `:`

Comment: sorry it's a typo when I wrote the question description. Updated!

Comment: this still won't fix the error that he was noticing